# Which settings are needed to display manual focus aids on the gx9 when using manual lenses?

Tags: camera-settings, manual-focus, panasonic

I have recently got a panasonic gx9 camera to complement my canon system.

I have been struggling to get manual focus aids to work, I have at one point managed to get it to display some kind of ”zebra” highlighting on the in focus areas and from time to time I get it to display a picture in picture mode magnifying the middle of the viewfinder.

I feel utterly confused by the menues and wonder if anyone knows which settings affect this.

Which settings should I use to enable the different manual focus aids when using manual lenses?

If it is important I am adapting many lenses firts to EF mount and then to m43 via the viltrox EF-M1, the EF adapter and lens is entierly non electronic thou.

Comment: Have you read the [manual](https://www.panasonic.hk/usm.ashx/e/7zt1rwYXAiWEX1X3Hkyy9JjPVqfCFPeA_n4SOS2Ut8CDLsS6NxnAIT13yGmAHwArt8d~8Nea6-aIFrETr5JpVTF29~l7VZZbcmu3OdUO-ubDqX49hcBmhfnBsON93kVXvegH1PUnii4JzYPS9NHC-Aoo/GX9-Eng-Manual.pdf)?